# How to google feedbuner?

Tags: feedback, subscribe

now, i'm developing a website for myself, i'd like to let the guests subscribe my website,and i saw other website use google sfeedburner to approval it, so i'd like to know how to use it for my user to subscribe my site.Please anyone know that?

Answer (score 0):

http://support.google.com/feedburner/answer/79408/?&

First you construct a machine readable version of your content (XML or ATOM for example). 
Then you publish that via feedburner.

Simples!

Comment: It seems not complicated, one more question please, if i use google burner, when i update my RSS page and issue some new contents, and my subscribers will get new contents pushed by google burner, right?

Comment: yes, it acts as a proxy between you user and your content. If you've correctly wired up your content to feedburner then it should act as you say.